# Remove Duplicate rows from DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I am using ASP.NET `DataGrid` Class. [asp:DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I want to remove certain rows based on the following condition.

**For Example:**

```
Complaint-Number        Attempts   Time
6000000939              1          11:02:00
6000000939              2          11:04:00
6000000939              3          11:09:00
```

I want to keep only those Complaints which has the highest Attempts like.

```
Complaint-Number        Attempts   Time
6000000939              3          11:09:00
```

I tried this Example but still no luck [Eliminate Duplicate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36697/Eliminate-Duplicate-Values-from-the-Grid-View)

**NOTE:** Please note that I am using **asp:DataGrid** class.

Please find the Screenshot of my report for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Select` statement try something like this.:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable 
WHERE (Attempts IN
               (SELECT MAX(Attempts) AS Expr1
                FROM yourTable AS yourTable_1))
```

It is called `Subquery` and you can read more about it here: [Subquery Fundamentals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: This is Solve my question  `WHERE A.attempt in (SELECT MAX(B.attempt) FROM AutoRectifier1 B WHERE A.TICKET_NO = B.TICKET_NO)`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DISTINCT Complaint-Number FROM yourtable ORDER BY Attempts ASC

You can use ORDER BY Attempts DESC as you need.